# iPhone 5s - apps, contacts, calendar, and ... don't synch from iMac

Tags: itunes, macos, imac, ios, iphone

Relevant harware and software:

- 27" iMac (earliest version)
- OS X 10.9.4 (latest version)
- iPhone 5s (brand new)
- iOS 7.1.2 (latest version)
- iTunes 11.3 (54) (latest version)

Note: I have no back up of any previous phone, because I wanted a completely clean installation and configuration to try to avoid problems I had with earlier iPhones.

I have a new iPhone 5s, I plugged into my computer, opened iTunes, configured it, selected everything I wanted to sync ***to it*** from my iMac and proceeded to sync it.

hmmmm....? ;-(

None of the following synched to the iPhone.

- contacts
- calendars
- notes
- email or email accounts
- bookmarks for Safari

I haven't checked everything else, but this doesn't look friendly.

Oddly, apps, music and photos did sync to the iPhone from the computer.

In iTunes (with the iPhone connected to my iMac, I selected the device and checked the following under the Info tab and clicked on Sync.  Still nothing.

[image: InfoSync]

Any ideas?

---

Late addition, apparently iOS and an iPhone 5s will no longer configure email settings from Apple mail.  If anyone is listening from Apple - this is silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found this which points to part of the answer:

http://www.macworld.com/article/2057971/sync-contacts-and-calendars-with-your-iphone-via-itunes-not-in-mavericks-you-dont.html

**Sync contacts and calendars with your iPhone via iTunes? Not in Mavericks you don't**

There may be more than 200 new feature in OS X Mavericks, the latest version of the Mac OS. But while Apple giveth it also taketh away: The ability to sync contact and calendars stored locally on your Mac with an iOS device is gone.

...

Is this an insidious plot to get everyone to use iCloud for syncing? Well yes, sort of. A tech note on Apple’s website explains:

```
 If you use OS X Mavericks v.10.9 or later, your contacts, calendars, and other info are updated on your computers and iOS devices via iCloud.
```

So there you have it.